# Application using Bing Maps API

Tags: c#, bing-maps

I need to create an application where user can enter Longitude and Latitude in TextBox and it will show a MAP using BING API. I need to show the Acquisition Date of Bird's Eye View and satellite View in the Map. Also an option that user can show the acquisition date to some third person.

How can I retrieve Acquisition Date and get location in Map using BING API? Can you write few lines of C# code to demonstrate?

Umair

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MSDN guides include samples very close to this.  The latitude/longitude portion is part of the guide itself.  ([MSDN Bing Maps .NET Getting started article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd221354.aspx))  Look down in the section on Retrieving Imagery Metadata to get further information on the image acquisition information.

Comment: Thanks for your reply of help but what I need is that I am building a silverlight application and I have Map control, 2 TextBoxes and a Button. When user will enter Lon and Lat and will press "Locate", the map control show show view of the location as well as information about the view image in a box some where near it.

Makes sense?

Comment: well that really helped! do you have similar link for Google Maps also. I want to extract the image and its meta data using google maps now.

Comment: sorry, I have never seen anything like that for Google Maps.